# PhpStorm and Firefox: open a link from Symfony Profiler

Tags: symfony, firefox, phpstorm

### EDIT

##### working fine now with new version of [PhpStormProtocol](https://github.com/aik099/PhpStormProtocol)

Despite all my attempts, I can't manage to open a link in PhpStorm when clicking in the Symfony Profiler or on an error link in Firefox.

PhpStorm gives me the following error:

```
Cannot find file 'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\phpstorm:\open?url=file:\C:\wamp\www\myproject\src\AppBundle\Controller\AppController.php&line=17'
```

In Symfony project config.html I put:

```
framework
    ide: "phpstorm://open?url=file://%%f&line=%%l"
```

I have added `network.protocol-handler.expose.phpstorm = false` in Firefox.

I also installed [PhpStormProtocol](https://github.com/aik099/PhpStormProtocol) and got the same error.

Comment: Apparently, the framework renders the link incorrectly - it has the Firefox path appended, and it definitely should not.

Comment: @EugeneMorozov, yes the Firefox part seems to be the problem. You think it is rendered by the ide ?

Comment: You can check that by simply copying the link from the browser into the copy-paste buffer.

Comment: @EugeneMorozov I don't know if it's so easy. The link does not contain the "Mozilla part", but how could phpStorm add this part ? I thought it would be Firefox, through the protocol-handler I guess, that's adding it.

Comment: Honestly, I don't think it's PhpStorm that's adding it. There's no just no functionality for that. Please remove the protocol handler taken from GitHub and try to configure it manually in the Windows registry.

Comment: @EugeneMorozov Following your advice, I removed the PhpStormProtocol and made my onwn entries in registry, but not sure how to use it. When I click the link, Firefox still asks me to choose the program that will open it and I end up with the same error.